# Git merge accidental commit to development branch

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a project with a master branch and a development branch. All changes should be committed in the development branch. I accidentally committed to the master branch and pushed it to Github. This commit is needed in the development branch. Since it is hard to undo the last push I think it might be a good idea to merge this commit to the development branch and then I merge the development branch back to the master branch.

If I do this:

```
git fetch origin
git branch
```

I get this:

```
* master
```

And if I do this:

```
git checkout development
```

I get this:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
(all kinds of files)
Aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have private files to clean before being able to change branch, I would recommend fixing the situation in a new clone first:

```
git clone https://username@github.com/username/reponame anewclone
cd anewclone
git checkout -b development --track origin/development
git merge master
git checkout master
git merge development
git checkout development
git push origin development
git push origin master
```

Then you can consider what are the files on your original repo that differs from development index in your second clone:

```
cd anewclone
git --work-tree=/path/to/first/clone status
```

That will use your second clone, but with the working tree of the first, and will allow you to add any missing file.

Comment: If you don't push master, why the dance merging into it (which just advances it to `development`, because there is no fetch in between and therefore it is necessarily fast-forward)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have local files unknown to `master`, but known to `development`. If you are not afraid of losing changes made to these local files, you can add the force flag `-f` to checkout:

```
git checkout -f development
```

I would look at the files that git complains about (do save them in a separate folder if that makes you feel safer), and where they might have come from.